# Input size issue when using lapply to mutate with R

Tags: r, lapply, dplyr

I have `mylist` which contains 2 lists, with sample data below.
Using `class(mylist[[1]])` gives  `"grouped_df"` `"tbl_df"` `"tbl"` `"data.frame"`

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Year, Commodity [2]
   Year Commodity Commodity.Code value1_k value2_k
  <int> <chr>     <int>          <dbl>    <dbl>
1  2010 A         721            100      100
2  2010 B         792            200      200

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Year, Commodity [2]
   Year Commodity Commodity.Code value1_m value2_m
  <int> <chr>     <int>          <dbl>    <dbl>
1  2010 A         721            100      100
2  2010 B         792            200      200
```

I tried using `mutate()` to add a new column `div` to both tibbles, with the value derived by dividing the 4th by the 5th column, using the code below:

```
mylist2 <- lapply(1:2, function(i){
  mylist[[i]] %>% mutate(div=.[[4]] /.[[5]])
})
```

This brings up the error below:

```
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `div`.
x Input `div` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `div` is `.[[4]]/.[[5]]`.
i Input `div` must be size 1, not 2.
i The error occurred in group 1: Year = 2010, Commodity = "A".
```

### Trying to reproduce the problem

I tried to reproduce the problem with dataset `cars`,
but the code worked this time.

```
cars1 <- cars +1
cars2 <- cars +2 
cars_all <- list(cars1,cars2)

lapply(1:2, function(i){
  cars_all[[i]] %>% mutate(div = .[[1]] / .[[2]])
})
```

Comparing both list of lists, I take note that the classes are different, i.e.

- `class(cars_all[[1]])` gives `"data.frame"`
- `class(mylist[[1]])` gives  `"grouped_df"` `"tbl_df"` `"tbl"` `"data.frame"`

However, I tried using `as.data.frame` before applying lapply, but the problem persists.

I use `lapply` because the actual mylist contains more lists;
I use index form to perform division instead of column names because the column names are different (and important, to be preserved) across lists.

My goal is to **add the extra column with its value derived through division** as mentioned.
If there are better methods out there to achieve this please let me know.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the grouping is what's causing the issue. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Commodity, ~Commodity.Code, ~value1_k, ~value2_k,
  2010,        "A",             721,       100,       100,
  2010,        "B",             792,       200,       200
) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Commodity)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Commodity, ~Commodity.Code, ~value1_k, ~value2_k,
  2011,        "C",            7242,       111,       123,
  2011,        "D",            7421,       222,       234
) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Commodity)

str(df1)
#>grouped_df[,5] [2 × 5] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
str(df2)
#>grouped_df[,5] [2 × 5] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)

mylist <- list(df1, df2)

mylist2 <- lapply(1:2, function(i){
  mylist[[i]] %>% mutate(div=.[[4]] /.[[5]])
})
#>Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `div`.
#>x Input `div` can't be recycled to size 1.
#>ℹ Input `div` is `.[[4]]/.[[5]]`.
#>ℹ Input `div` must be size 1, not 2.
#>ℹ The error occurred in group 1: Year = 2010, Commodity = "A".

mylist2 <- lapply(1:2, function(i){
  mylist[[i]] %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(div=.[[4]] /.[[5]])
})
mylist2
#>[[1]]
#> A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   Year Commodity Commodity.Code value1_k value2_k   div
#>  <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>1  2010 A                    721      100      100     1
#>2  2010 B                    792      200      200     1

#>[[2]]
#> A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   Year Commodity Commodity.Code value1_k value2_k   div
#>  <dbl> <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>1  2011 C                   7242      111      123 0.902
#>2  2011 D                   7421      222      234 0.949
```

Does this work on your 'real' data?

Comment: Yes! It worked!! I picked up R from scratch and didn't understand the basics. Will look up later on more info about groupings. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: No problem at all - thank you for including all the necessary info in your question